# Understand average time current curve of a fuse

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, fuses

When I made my buck-boost converter (12v input) (1-20v 4A output max) I choose a 7A fast blow fuse at the input in base to the calc 80w/12V = 6.66A.
Suppose my dc-dc converter drives 5A to output (cause the current control pot is not exact to 4A, maybe 4.5-5A max), did the fuse survive to that output current?
I look at the average time current of the fuse but I not understand very well. In the curve regarding to 7A in the "x" of the graphic the curve is marked 100A and that's what confuse me.

[image: fuse table]
Datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_Fuse_251_253_Datasheet_pdf-522535.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Let's clean up that chart to make it more readable.

Because if it's your first time looking at one of these, the chart they gave you is a hot mess.

[image]

See, the manufacturer crammed all their fuses onto one chart.  I've eliminated all the fuses you don't own, so the only one left is your 7A fuse.  *That's less confusing, eh?*

Note that this is a log chart.  That means the axis is *exponential* not linear.  Each "major division" of the chart is 10 times the last.  Look at how I marked 1-80 amps, the gap gets significantly smaller for each unit.

Look at the distance between 1 and 2.  It's the same distance as between 2 and 4.  And 4 and 8.  On a log chart, doubling will be the same distance.

You would use a log chart to show things which change exponentially to where a linear graph would be much too tall (or smush all the smaller data if you shrank it).  For instance I plot COVID cases in the US, and the November wave is so big that it makes the March and July waves look like nothing *if the plot is linear*.

This chart, however is a *log-log* graph.  Because it's not only looking at a huge range of fuses(1/16 to 20A), it's also looking at a huge range of trip times (milliseconds to minutes).

Once you get the hang of log graphs, this becomes more obvious.

### The trip curve gives you Amps vs Time-to-trip.

You can now see the "7 amp" line, (purple 7), and follow that vertical line... as you can see, this line never touches the trip.

Between 1 second and 100 seconds, the trip line appears to be straight.  And now you know  how to read a log chart, you can interpolate what that value is.  It looks like "11 amps", but remember it's a log chart.  **It's probably 10.5 amps, which is exactly 150% of 7A**.

This chart is saying that the fuse will tolerate up to 10.5 amps *indefinitely*.  That's probably not *quite* true, I'm sure there's a manufacturing tolerance in there.

So now you can read the chart.  If you overload this fuse to 30 amps, expect a trip within .01 seconds.  Etc.

Honestly their efforts to cram all fuses onto 1 chart really obfuscated a lot of useful detail.  For instance, here is a trip curve for a residential breaker, which is not a simple curve because there are 2 trip mechanisms. One thermal like your fuse... and also a magnetic trip, which causes the L-shaped bottom part of the curve.

[image]

This chart is written *as a multiple of* the stated trip current on the breaker handle.  That lets them use the same chart for 15, 20, 40, 60 and 100A breakers... which means they have room on the chart to show actual manufacturing tolerance!  In this case if you had a 10A breaker, and overloaded it to 20A, you'd get a trip between 9 and 35 seconds.  This is typical of residential breakers, which protect wiring in the walls, which take some time to overheat.  The generous headroom allows surge loads like motor starts, halogen inrush current, etc.

Breakers with curves like this are generally made for clipping into service panels, but some are offered in DIN rail or chassis-mountable form factors.

Comment: Harper its so clear your explanation!! You take the job of cleaning up the graph and leave only relevant information. I get it perfectly!, by the way I asume this fuse will last forever at 9A because like you said is difficult as a manufacture thing say that this fuse last at 10A by looking at the graph.

Comment: The point about manufacturing tolerance is important. The shaded area on the lower chart shows that SOME 20A breakers of this line might withstand only 20A (1x) indefinitely, whereas others might withstand 25A (1.25x). All products, including your fuses, have manufacturing tolerances, but your datasheet isn't showing them on the graph. Your 7A fuse probably does NOT promise to last forever at anything over 7A, but it does not promise ever to trip at 7A either, or even at 9A. (I say _probably_ because the graph doesn't show this information, and I didn't read the datasheet.)

Comment: eh?  Ambient temperature from air and recent power history from stored energy also affect tolerances. But the obfuscation is not the charts but the specs for why they didn't make it clear and say  "Must Hold" , "May Trip" (nom) and "Must Trip"

Comment: Good point Tony, for instance the Square D chart only shows from ambient, it doesn't show what happens if you draw 2X rated current immediately after drawing 1.0x rated current for an hour.   Or if your panel is outdoors in a cold snap etc.  Or in an attic.

Answer (score 7):

> Suppose my dc-dc converter drives 5A to output (cause the current control pot is not exact to 4A, maybe 4.5-5A max), did the fuse survive to that output current?

A 7A fast-blow fuse will last basically "forever" on 5A.

> In the curve regarding to 7A in the "x" of the graphic the curve is marked 100A and that's what confuse me.

If the 7A fuse is fed 100A, it will blow in 0.001 seconds. That quantity is found by looking at the scale on the left hand side. Notice that at about 15A the fuse will last about 0.1 second, and at 30A it will last about 0.01 seconds.

Comment: Excelent your response, but i have one more question. What makes you think a 7A fuse will blow forever at 5A? I mean i believe you but where i can get that info. Thanks so much

Comment: Excellent Math, I get it. The thing is that the fuse is at input of the dc-dc converter as I said at the beginning of the post, so in base of my calc at 20v 5A output for example, the input voltage of the converter would be 12v and the fuse will have to handle 100W/12V = 8.33A so the answer would be, "the fuse will blow" right?

Comment: A 7A fuse is not guaranteed to survive 8.33A. However, it is not guaranteed to blow either. If you look at the graph, the 7A fuse can survive 11A for 100 seconds, according to the  conditions (temperature) they test them. (If the temperature is high, perhaps a 7A fuse will blow with less current.) If a fuse can survive 100 seconds at 11A, it _might_ be able to survive much much longer. I wouldn't rely on it either way.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info Math. I understand everything now with your last response.

Answer (score 5):

### ALSO

The fuse rating is for Holding current
and the A^2t (amp^2sec) is a thermal energy-related value to define the nominal Fusing current at 25'C ambient, which is defined by the curve, which starts around 40% above the holding value.

e.g. a 3.5A will hold 3.5A and may hold 4A forever or even 5A which is the nominal threshold and then faster for higher currents.

5A/3.5A = 1.43 x100%

[image]

But then if you thought it was wise to use a 3.5A fuse fora 4A DC supply, you better be prepared for a much shorter MTBF on the fuse as its lifespan reduces 50% for every 10'C rise above room temp.  So if you really want surge protection for thermal damage, you better design that another way.

Comment: I was wondering when I saw this, is it acceptable practice to exceed the nominal value of a fuse by a small planned margin or is it best practice never to disturb the "padding"?  7.3A for example.

Comment: If you make it too high you might never blow it before the regulator fails if it has no OCP over-current protection

Comment: Excellent Tony, I get it perfectly!

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like "What is a log-log graph?" and "how do I read fuse/breaker trip curve charts" are the questions of the hour.

Answer (score 3):

> When I made my buck-boost converter (12v input) (1-20v 4A output max)
> I choose a 7A fast blow fuse at the input in base to the calc 80w/12V
> = 6.66A. Suppose my dc-dc converter drives 5A to output (cause the current control pot is not exact to 4A, maybe 4.5-5A max), did the
> fuse survive to that output current?

The fuse might survive it's on the input, so you're correct to calculate wattage, but your converter is not 100% efficient, so at 5A 20V (80W) on the output, it will have slightly more than that on the input.  7A*12V=84W calculates your maximum input power, so if your converter is 90% efficient, you multiply that by 90% and get a max output power of 75.6W.  In reality there's a tiny bit of headroom because a 7A fuse doesn't guarantee it will blow at 7A, it guarantees it won't blow at 7A, so at currents only slightly above that it won't blow or it will take a very long time.

I think where you're getting confused is that the number at the top of the graph that says 15A pointing to a line means that is the trip point for a 15A fuse. So once you find the line marked 7A for your fuse you can follow it down.  The line shows that for smaller amounts of time the fuse can take more than its rated current.

Comment: Yeah exactly like you said. After I read your answer I can get it. Thanks!